# Loop through layers of URLs with R and scrape data

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am working on a school project that involves using R to scrape player attributes from https://www.baseball-reference.com and build a data frame with them. The website has all of the players listed alphabetically, and I have written the code that creates a url for each letter below:

```
# every baseball player is identified by their last name, using all the 
letters allows me to build urls with the letters
ltrs <- letters

# create an empty container for the urls
url_container <- c()

# this is the base url I append letters to
url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/"

# use a for loop to create the urls
for(i in 1:length(ltrs)){
  url_start = paste(url, ltrs[i], "/", sep = '')
  url_container = c(url_container, url_start)
}

# print the container to make sure the urls are correctly constructed
url_container

# This Outputs: [1] <https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/> 
  <https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/b/> etc.
```

Every page also has a certain number of players, which I am able to grab with the following code, which outputs a list of the number of players url.

```
player_quantity <- c()

for(i in 1:length(url_container)){
  raw = read_html(url_container[i])
  player_count <- raw %>%
  # this is where the player count lives
  html_nodes(.,xpath="//*[@id='all_players_']/div[1]/h2") %>%
  # cast the value as an integer (it will define how many tags we go through)
  html_text(.)
  player_quantity <- c(player_quantity, player_count)
}

player_quantity <- as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", player_quantity))
player_quantity

# Outputs this: 
[1]  593 1847 1504  945  352  691 1056 1395   58  505  706  885 2015  337  360  925   49 1065 1894  637
[21]   60  269 1075    0  113   93
```

What I'm struggling to do is use those elements to loop through every, copy the URL for each player and then run my code to pull the player attributes (which I have written and which works, but is not applicable to this question.)

The XPaths for the players look like this: "//*[@id="div_players_"]/p[1]/a" and here is the code I've written/ copied from [Reading table from https webpage using readHTMLTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058164/reading-table-from-https-webpage-using-readhtmltable) thus far, but while it runs it doesn't seem to return anything and I'm not sure why.

```
mainweb="https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/"

urls = read_html("https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/") %>%
html_nodes("#active a") %>%
html_attrs()

teamdata=c()
j=1
for(i in urls){
  bball <- html(paste(mainweb, i, sep=""))
  teamdata[j]= bball %>%
  html_nodes(paste0("#", gsub("/teams/([A-Z]+)/$","\\1", urls[j], perl=TRUE))) 
  %>%
  html_table()
  j=j+1
}
```

Any help or ideas would be definitely appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534808/web-scraping-looping-through-list-of-ids-and-years-in-r/45536419#45536419

Comment: Hi @Dave2e, I had not come across that question for some reason, thanks for pointing it out! It does help somewhat, however its a simplification of my question - I want to loop through every player, meaning I have to go to each "letter" url (urls listing players w/ last name beginning w/ "A", "B" etc.). This question pulls the data for the players just on that one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you to the point of having all of the names and their associated links. From there you should be able to loop or map over the links and apply the processing and/or `html_table` extraction:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

base_url <- "https://www.baseball-reference.com"

# Only doing this for the first four letters, just change to letters[1:26]
links_by_letter <- paste0(base_url, "/players/", letters[1:4])

# Create a function that returns the links for a given letter
get_links_for_letter <- function(url) {
  # Using httr::RETRY in case we are burdening the server
  link_elements <- read_html(httr::RETRY("GET", url)) %>%
    html_nodes("#div_players_ a")

  links <- link_elements %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    paste0(base_url, .) %>%
    set_names(., nm = link_elements %>% html_text)

  return(links)
}

# Make 'safe' version that throws an NA in case we do not get anything back.
safe_get_links_for_letter <- possibly(~ get_links_for_letter(.x), otherwise = NA)

results <- 
  links_by_letter %>%
  map(~ safe_get_links_for_letter(.)) %>%
  map_df(enframe)

head(results)
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   name          value                                                       
#   <chr>         <chr>                                                       
# 1 David Aardsma https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/aardsda01.shtml
# 2 Hank Aaron    https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/aaronha01.shtml
# 3 Tommie Aaron  https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/aaronto01.shtml
# 4 Don Aase      https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/aasedo01.shtml 
# 5 Andy Abad     https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/abadan01.shtml 
# 6 Fernando Abad https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/abadfe01.shtml 

tail(results)

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   name             value                                                       
#   <chr>            <chr>                                                       
# 1 Radhames Dykhoff https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/d/dykhora01.shtml
# 2 Allan Dykstra    https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/d/dykstal01.shtml
# 3 Lenny Dykstra    https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/d/dykstle01.shtml
# 4 John Dyler       https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/d/dylerjo01.shtml
# 5 Jarrod Dyson     https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/d/dysonja01.shtml
# 6 Sam Dyson        https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/d/dysonsa01.shtml
```

Comment: Wow, thanks @JasonAizkalns! I didn't know how to do this in so few lines. I'm brand new to R/ this is my first project in R, so I apologize if this question was super basic.

Comment: @NLourme - it's not that basic of a question, but I think the way you worded it is why you have the downvotes. Try to focus on the core of your question and you're likely to get a better response. Using the tidyverse/purrr + functions really helps break this down into more manageable parts. A nice plan of attack is: Try to get things working for one "thing" (one item, one link), then scale it up via loops/map.